# Получение коллекций из базы данных SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, коллекции

Мне нужно получить в коллекцию данные из  базы данных 
Мне нужно наполнить ее данными из MS SQL Server 
Код коллекции.

```
    class CityBD
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public int Square { get; set; }

    public static CityBD[] GetCityBDs()
    {
        var result = new CityBD[]
        {
            new CityBD() { Title = "Москва", Company = "Россия", price = "абвг", Square = 1 },
            new CityBD() { Title = "Вашингтон", Company = "США", price = "абвг", Square = 2 }
        };
        return result;




    }
}
```

}

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы данные брались с SQL сервера. 
Код SQL

```
 USE [mobiledb]
 GO
 /** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_InsertPhone]    Script Date: 20.05.2019 22:02:06 **/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertPhone]
    @title nvarchar(50),
    @company nvarchar(50),
    @price int,
    @Square int,
    @Date date,
    @Id int out

AS
    INSERT INTO Phones (Title, Company, Price,Square,Date)
    VALUES (@title, @company, @price,@Square,@Date)
   SET @Id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Пожалуйста конкретизируйте Ваш вопрос. Какая база данных у Вас установлена, на каком порту "висит". есть ли в базе данные? В какой таблицы и код программы.

Comment: Скажите, я правильно понял, что Вам надо сделать выборку из таблицы Phones и материализовать ее в коллекцию элементов типа CityBD?

Comment: Да все правильно

Comment: Параметр `Price` в sql объявлен `int`, в C# - `string`. А по сути это вообще должен быть `decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать для загрузки из БД статический метод в самом классе модели -- идея не из лучших, для этого стоит создать отдельный класс, примерно такой:

```
public class PhonesLoader
{
    private const string SelectAllQuery = @"SELECT Title, Company, Price, Square FROM Phones";

    private readonly string _connectionString;


    public PhonesLoader(string connectionString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }


    public CityBD[] GetAll()
    {
        var result = new List<CityBD>();

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.Type = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = SelectAllQuery;

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var titleColumnName = reader.GetOrdinal(nameof(CityBD.Title));
                var companyColumnName = reader.GetOrdinal(nameof(CityBD.Company));
                var priceColumnName = reader.GetOrdinal(nameof(CityBD.Price));
                var squareColumnName = reader.GetOrdinal(nameof(CityBD.Square));

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var record = new CityBD();

                    record.Title = reader.GetString(titleColumnName);
                    record.Company = reader.GetString(companyColumnName);
                    record.Price = reader.GetString(priceColumnName);
                    record.Square = reader.GetInt32(squareColumnName);

                    result.Add(record);
                }
            }
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Безусловно, код очень упрощен, но, надеюсь, поможет Вам понять, куда двигаться дальше.
Скорее всего в Вашу модель CityBD надо еще добавить Id.

Comment: Получение индексов с помощью `GetOrdinal` вынести из цикла (поставить выше `while`) - и будет вообще здорово.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, и правда, сейчас поправлю, спасибо.